# Paypal IPN simulator issue

Tags: java, servlets, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Although lots of people have asked this question and I have gone through many of them but unable to fix my issue. I think its simple but unfortunately I am stuck here.

I am able to hit my listener externally but not getting from IPN simulator. Getting the following error

[image]

any help is highly appreicated.

cheers!

Comment: Oddly, I can only get the PayPal IPN simulator to work with a hostname, and it refuses to connect to a URL with a naked IP address. Would you happen to have a domain name you could point toward the IP address so your handler URL doesn't have the naked IP address in it?

Comment: @nasonfish wow man....it works...if you put your comment as n answer I'll accept it...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get around to posting the answer until now; I'm glad that helped, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a "raw" IP address in the target URL appears to be prevented by PayPal's IPN simulator; I've been testing it out and it seems that the simulator will only send a request if you use a domain name in place of the IP address.

So, instead of an address like `http://1.2.3.4/test.php`, if you have a domain name, you can set an `A` or `AAAA` record on the domain name to point to your IP address, and then replace the "naked" part of the URL - the `1.2.3.4` - with the domain name, like `stackoverflow.com`, so you'd end up with `http://stackoverflow.com/test.php`, which still should send you to the same endpoint as you were previously attempting to send the request to.

It's odd that this restriction would be in place, it could possibly be a bug that PayPal overlooked since I can't find any documentation on the subject, but that's one way to get around the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

This has been confirmed by Paypal; pasted below from an incident I opened with them.

---

> Hello,
>
> That's correct, you need to use a domain name if you want to test with
>   IPN simulator.
>
> The way around it is to use either a LIVE or SANDBOX account and add
>   the IPN URL with the IP address instead of a domain name.
>
> ie: http://8.8.8.8/paypal/paypal-ipn.php
>
> This will work outside of the IPN simulator.
>
> Regards Justin MTS

---

> Can you confirm that the IPN Simulator does not work with IP addresses
>   as suggested by this post?
>   [Paypal IPN simulator issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792194/paypal-ipn-simulator-issue)
>
> I am trying to test the G2 => G5 SSL certificate upgrade. Is there
>   anyway around this or do I have to buy a domain just to perform
>   testing?
>
> Thanks Joe