# PayPal IPN Simulator: Something went wrong while trying to connect to the URL. Please check the URL and try again

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am applying PayPal payment on the web application I'm building. I am trying to test IPN messages with IPN Simulator on my PayPal Sandbox account.

The issue is that IPN simulator is returning an error for the IPN listener URL `"Something went wrong while trying to connect to the URL. Please check the URL and try again."`. The URL is in format `http://123.123.123.123:1234/MyApp.WebAPI/api/transactions/ppIpnListener`. When I run the URL in the browser it is hitting the method. The address `123.123.123.123:1234` is my computer's address, visible to the "outside world" and the `MyApp.WebAPI` project is hosted in my computer's local IIS. The code is(C#):

```
[RoutePrefix("api/transactions")]
public class TransactionController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ppIpnListener")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void PPIpnListener()
    {
        //some code
    }
```

How to make IPN Simulator work?

Comment: Check your local IIS settings - does it accept external connections - and similar. That would be the first stop. If you want to validate this suggestion, then use an external service in the simulator, e.g.  [Requestb.in](http://requestb.in) so you can verify that IPN simulator works and pretty much narrows the issue down to _your_ environment.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not as an edit to your question

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792194/paypal-ipn-simulator-issue) the domain name should be used instead of an IP address(e.g. `http://www.example.com/MyApp.WebAPI/api/transactions/ppIpnListener`) and that should solve the issue.